# updating excel sheet in Selenium Parallel Testing

Tags: selenium, parallel-processing

I'm running a Selenium parallel tests using `TestNG` framework. everything working fine. My tests are picking up data from `excel sheet` and running parallel. Problem is when i want to update the results back to the `excel sheet` for each tests.

Result is updating only for specific testcases.
e.g.

> Test1 -->runs-->updates results back to the excel sheet(Basically a
>   column in excelsheet)
>
> Test1 -->runs-->updates results back to the excel sheet(Basically a
>   column in excelsheet)

Excelsheet column :

> ```
>  TestCase Name    Userid    Pwd         Results
>
>  TC1              12345     xyz          PASS
>
>  TC2              45678     abc           FAIL
> ```

Comment: Could you share the code which you are using to update the results in excel?

Comment: Are you updating the excel sheet at the end of each thread ? Or at the end of the whole job ?